# Microsoft Webview2 Navigate issue

Tags: vb.net, webview

Trying to create a Winforms app with VB.Net to automate capture of my website pages as images. I successfully did that on a page-per-page basis but am trying now to automate it.
Since this webview2 thing is rather new to me, I am running into an issue where the NavigateCompleted event is never fired up and I can't figure out why.

I should also add that WebView2 is obviously initialized first using Wb.EnsureCoreWebView2Async

I first grab all page names off the website, then I load each page in the webview.

Here's the code I use to loop through all pages:

```
For Each p As String In _MyPages
ActivePage = p
Wb.Source = New Uri(p)
Wb.CoreWebView2.Navigate(p)
Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
Next
```

And here's part of the code I added to the WebView NavigationCompleted event:

```
Private Async Sub Wb_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles Wb.NavigationCompleted
Dim imgfile As String
Dim NewPage As String
...
Dim msg As String

NewPage = ActivePage.Replace("/", "-")
If Mid(NewPage, NewPage.Length) = "-" Then
    NewPage = Mid(NewPage, 1, NewPage.Length - 1)
End If
imgfile = defdir & "\" & NewPage & ".jpg"

w = Await Wb.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.scrollWidth;")
scrollWidth = Val(w)
h = Await Wb.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.scrollHeight;")
scrollHeight = Val(h)
...
End Sub
```

Is there anything I do wrong and, if yes, what and where?

Thank you